# SQLite One-to-Many Relationship Set/Get Foreign Key

Tags: java, android, sqlite, one-to-many

I am building an android app project with SQLite DB.

I got stuck on One-To-Many RelationShip.

This is One

```
private static final String createTableOrders =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ORDER + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                ...
                + KEY_COLUMN_FORMATS + " INTEGER REFERENCES " + TABLE_FORMATS + "(" + KEY_ID + ")"
                + ");";
```

This is Many

```
private static final String createTableFormats =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FORMATS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                  ...
                + ");";
```

My problems is with set/get methods. 
Lets say that I would need to get list of ids of all Formats that are in one Order.
I guess same thing goes for set method.

I tried to find this kind of question on SO but most of the question were just for SQL part.

P.S. Spent 3 hours trying to make it by myself but the only thing I got to was using GSON to code list of ids into String but it was just a dead-end.

EDIT: I need to get that information inside the code.

P.S.S I have been doing this for 18 hours so sorry if this is uber-stupid question.

Comment: `"select distinct " + KEY_COLUMN_FORMATS + " from " + TABLE_ORDER`?

Comment: usually the "many-side" has a foreign key to the "one-side" so in my opinion "TABLE_FORMATS" should have a foreingn key to "TABLE_ORDER".

Comment: Just had a relevation... I guess it will be just some Query and loading it with cursor but it will doesnt answer how to create that relationship ( getMethod) .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A one-to-many relationship requires the foreign key column in the "many" table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    ID PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE Formats (
    ID PRIMARY KEY,
    OrderID REFERENCES Orders(ID)
);
```

To get all formats belonging to an order, you just look up rows with the ID of that order:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Formats WHERE OrderID = ?
```

In Jave:

```java
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_FORMATS,
                         new String[] { whatever columns you need },
                         "OrderID = " + orderID,
                         null, null, null, null, null);
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    // read one order from the cursor
}
cursor.close();
```

Comment: And how do I save an object that has one to many relationship?

Comment: You insert a bunch of table rows with the appropriate values. Java/Android itself does not have built-in helpers for that.

Comment: My Patient class has a one-to-many relationship with the Foto class, my create looked like this: `db.execSQL("create table paciente(_id integer primary key autoincrement, nome varchar(50), cpf varchar(11), data varchar(15) )");
        db.execSQL("create table fotos(_id integer primary key autoincrement, enviado int(2), fotoBitmap BLOB, pacieent_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(fk_pacienteId) REFERENCES paciente(_id))");`

Comment: What does it look like in content values? `ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("nome", paciente.getNome());
        values.put("cpf", paciente.getCpf());
        values.put("data", paciente.getData());
        values.put("foto",imageInBytes);

        long result  = banco.insert("paciente", null, values);
        if(result == -1){
            return 0;
        }else{
            return result;
        }`

Comment: i'm new to sqlite and i'm having a hard time finding help in the forums because besides making this relationship one to a lot, in the photo class i need to save a list of photos that were captured by the app. can you help me please?

Comment: To ask a question, click the "Ask Question" button.